# ElasticSearch search on some field not working

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my sample document

```
{
  "_index": "my_index_log",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "50688-63-22-null",
  "_version": 56,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "documentId": "50688-63-22-null",
    "primaryId": 50688,
    "cId": 63,
    "oI": 63,
    "code": "22",
    "errorCount": 56,
    "firstSeenAt": 1577420695319,
    "lastSeenAt": 1581339916000
  }
}
```

When I search on Kibana on `primaryId`, `cId`, it works fine without any issue. However, when I search on `errorCount`, `firstSeenAt` and `lastSeenAt`, search does not result on exact match.

Also, note that `errorCount` and `lastSeenAt` are updated whenever an error message is seen.

What is the reason that search is not working?

Edit: Output of `GET my_index_log/_mappings`

```
{
    "my_index_log": {
        "mappings": {
            "_doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "cId": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "documentId": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "errorCount": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "errorType": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "firstSeenAt": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "primaryId": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "lastSeenAt": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "oI": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the reason is the different datatype of your field. Elasticsearch inherit from java datatypes and subvided string into two types: text and keywords. Could you post the output of GET my_index_log/_mappings ?

Comment: @Lupanoide: Please see the edit.

Comment: could you please post the queries you wrote to march the `primaryId` and the one you wrote to match the `errorCount`? I don't see any reason why they shouldn't work the same way, besides the fact that by the time you run the query the value of the field has changed.

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, what happens if you create a `range` query that matches any document with `errorCount` greater-or-equal to the value that you would like to match?

Comment: I checked through kibana. It has payload in the following comment.

Comment: `{"index":"ota_hotel_mapping_error*","ignore_unavailable":true,"timeout":30000,"preference":1581339935620}
{"version":true,"size":500,"sort":[{"_score":{"order":"desc"}}],"_source":{"excludes":[]},"stored_fields":["*"],"script_fields":{},"docvalue_fields":[],"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"errorCount > 4","analyze_wildcard":true,"default_field":"*"}}],"filter":[],"should":[],"must_not":[]}},"highlight":{"pre_tags":["@kibana-highlighted-field@"],"post_tags":["@/kibana-highlighted-field@"],"fields":{"*":{}},"fragment_size":2147483647}}`